# posfix not send/recieve mail to other server

Tags: postfix, dovecot

On server installed Debian 7.8, Postfix 2.9.6, Dovecot 2.1.7.
The server does not receive or send mail to external servers. Within a domain, everything works.

Config files:

```
/etc/hosname
    vps-***.kz
```

Hostname can not be changed, it is setted hoster company.

```
/etc/mailname
    mail.domain.kz
```

Posfix config files:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
    smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
    biff = no
    append_dot_mydomain = no
    readme_directory = no
    myhostname = mail.domain.kz
    mydomain = domain.kz
    mydestination =  mail.domain.kz, localhost.domain.kz, localhost, vps-***.kz, localhost.vps-***.kz
    myorigin = mail.domain.kz

    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
    recipient_delimiter = +
    inet_interfaces = all
    inet_protocols = ipv4

    smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/certs/postfix.pem
    smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/certs/private/postfix.pem
    smtpd_use_tls=yes
    smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
    smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

    virtual_uid_maps = static:3000
    virtual_gid_maps = static:3000
    virtual_minimum_uid = 3000

    mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
    virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_domain_maps.cf
    virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
    relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains.cf

    virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
    virtual_transport = dovecot
    dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1

    smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
         reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
         permit_mynetworks,
         reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
         reject_unauth_destination,
         reject_unverified_recipient,
         permit

    broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
    smtpd_delay_reject = yes
    smtpd_helo_required = yes
    strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
    disable_vrfy_command = yes

    max_use = 100
    mailbox_size_limit = 0
    default_process_limit = 100
    header_size_limit = 10485760
    message_size_limit = 104857600
    smtpd_error_sleep_time = 20s
    anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
    smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 100
    smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 250
    smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 250

    maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d
    bounce_queue_lifetime = 1d
    smtpd_milters = unix:/clamav/clamav-milter.ctl, unix:/spamass/spamass.sock
```

In log file is not written anything, empty files /var/log/mail.*. Syslog log file also empty.

Where may be a mistake?

Comment: install rsyslog and then post your output please.

Comment: I think logging is your big problem. If you had log files, the answer might be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP authentication is required for emails to be successfully delivered to  external users. 
Add the following lines to your main.cf : 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd